# Run maven tests in a DOS batch file

Tags: maven, batch-file, dos

I am new to scripting. Basically I want to run maven tests and then execute other commands once they're finished (e.g. Write a message to a file, or email the results to myself, etc. For simplicity, let's say I just want to write DONE to "C:/results" file in this case). This is the script that I have:

```
    mvn test
    echo "DONE" > C:/results
```

The problem is, the second line (echo) never executes, because first one (mvn test) never seems to finish, even though I can see from the output that running the test finished. 
How can I change the script to execute the rest of the commands once execution of first line (mvn test) finishes?

Comment: First: What kind of commands would like to run? Furthermore if you are on windows you have to be aware that `mvn` itself is `.bat` file which means you have to  do the following: `call mvn test`..

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. Can you explain why do I need to do this? Also, please post your comment as a reply, so I can chose it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows you have to be aware that `mvn` itself is `.bat` file which means you have to do the following: `call mvn test`

You need to do the `call...` cause the `mvn.bat` is running and ended at the end of `mvn.bat`. This is the way it is in Windows.

Comment: I am still not sure I understand why the "call" is used, so I am going to research it some more. Thanks for your answer. It resolved my issue.